# Youtube API - Listing hidden videos of my channel using OAuth

Tags: youtube, google-api, google-oauth

I need to list all my unlisted videos on a web page, using OAuth2.  Associated with my email, there are 2 channels.

I am using this code: [youtube/api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/my_uploads.html)

When I first authorize OAuth, it lists the videos I uploaded on the chosen account, then when I reload the page it says I don't have videos uploaded.

If i remove all the cookies and reauthorize again it works, then if i reload the page again I get the "No videos" message.

It seems that it tries to list the wrong channel when i reload, but I am sure I authorized the right channel.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Paste the http requests/responses from the dev console

Comment: I noted that after the refresh, the API gives me an incorrect, non existing playlistID. If I try to view it, it says that it doesn't exist. Here is a dump of the requests, I had to redact some ids, channel is not mine: http://pastebin.com/ir8yhc7H